# Haystack & ElasticSearch: Searching Related Fields; Use nested Type?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using django-haystack on elastic search.  My indexed documents each have a number of people's names and for each person, their role associated with the document.  For example:

```
Doc1:
   name='Bob',  role='Author'
   name='Jill', role='Editor'
   name='Joe',  role='Publisher'

Doc2:
   name='Jill',  role='Author'
   name='Phill', role='Editor'
   name='Janet', role='Contributor'
```

How would I setup my index to allow me to do the search: "find all documents where `Jill` is an `Author`"?  In the above example, I would want it to return only `Doc2` and **not** `Doc1`.

There are hundreds of different types of roles a person can have, so it isn't realistic to have an index field for each type.  I thought about having a single index field joining the two together (e.g., `name_role=indexes.CharField(...)`), where each entry has a delimiter that I would parse (e.g., `"Jill#Author"`). But that seems ugly.

Are there any better ways to do this?  I feel like [ElasticSearch's `nested` type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) may be able to help, but I'm not sure.

Even though I'm using django-haystack, if there is an elasticsearch specific answer, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, ElasticSearch's `nested` type is essential to get this working neatly. This is not by default supported by django-haystack (because it's ES-specific), but it is possible to support this functionality by extending some of haystack's classes.

There is a [blog post](http://www.stamkracht.com/extending-haystacks-elasticsearch-backend/) that explains this quite clearly (and a [gist](https://gist.github.com/aolieman/7929274) that can be forked).

Coincidentally, I wrote the post and @speedplane already found it, but hey.. ;-)

Comment: An issue that I found with this is that you cannot use faceting or aggregations with the nested types. I was able to workaround it, but it requires a change to `UnifiedIndex.get_facet_fieldname`

Comment: Interesting.. It looks like subclassing `UnifiedIndex` would be very annoying though. Did you monkeypatch the modified `get_facet_fieldname`?

Comment: Didn't feel like subclassing that beast, so I just monkeypatched it. I'd consider submitting an official patch, but I highly doubt it'll be accepted.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not so sure what's going on with Haystack ES-backend development. It would be interesting to see your workaround though! Maybe in a fork of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aolieman/7929274)?